# Como formatar uma coluna "date" dentro do de um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, data, data.frame

Estou com dificuldades em formatar uma coluna com datas no meu banco de dados.

Exemplo:

```
01/08/2018 06:02:44
```

Gostaria de formatar a coluna tirando o time e em outra coluna indicar o mês correspondente.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, vamos criar um exemplo reprodutível.

```
library(tidyverse)
tabela <- data_frame(timestamp = Sys.time())
```

E então é possível resolver a primeira questão assim:

```
tabela %>% 
  mutate(
    coluna_sem_time = as.Date(timestamp)
  )
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  timestamp           coluna_sem_time
  <dttm>              <date>         
1 2019-01-30 17:46:01 2019-01-30
```

E adicionar o mês

```
tabela %>% 
  mutate(
    mes = lubridate::month(timestamp)
  )
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  timestamp             mes
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2019-01-30 17:46:01     1
```

Ou fazer os dois de uma vez

```
tabela %>% 
  mutate(
    coluna_sem_time = as.Date(timestamp),
    mes = lubridate::month(timestamp)
  )
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  timestamp           coluna_sem_time   mes
  <dttm>              <date>          <dbl>
1 2019-01-30 17:46:01 2019-01-30          1
```

Answer (score 6):

Eu sou fã de usar o pacote `lubridate` para resolver todo e qualquer problema com data. Veja abaixo como obtive facilmente o que te interessava com funções de nomes bastante intuitivos:

```
library(lubridate)

data <- dmy_hms("01/08/2018 06:02:44")
data
[1] "2018-08-01 06:02:44 UTC"
date(data)
[1] "2018-08-01"
month(data)
[1] 8
```

Para conhecer mais funções do pacote, rode `?lubridate` em seu terminal e desça até o link `Index`, na parte inferior da página de ajuda que abrirá.

Comment: A minha dúvida é formatar esta data que já está dentro de um data.frame. Como posso formatar a data de uma coluna inteira?

Comment: Edita o post com uma amostra dos dados. Usa o comando `dput` pra isso.

Answer (score 4):

Também uso bastante o pacote `lubridate` mas, nesse caso, ela não é necessária. Basta usar a função `format()` que já vem carregada no pacote `base`:

```
tabela <- data.frame(timestamp = Sys.time()) # criar um data.frame com a data
```

Para objetos em formato `POSIXct`, use `format()` e especifique o que será formatado na data. Por exemplo, `format(x, "%Y")` preservará apenas o ano em formato de 4 dígitos (e.g. 2019). Já `format(x, "%y")` retirará apenas os dois últimos digitos do ano (e.g. o "19" de "2019"). `"%d"` e `"%m"` extrai o dia e o mês do objeto respectivamente. Portanto:

```
> format(tabela$timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "31-01-2019"

> format(tabela$timestamp, "%m")
[1] "01"
```